# JQuery Load all images inside div before display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to load every image inside a div before actually displaying them. I have something similar to this:

```
<div>

<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="1.jpg" />

</div>
```

At first I tried doing things like:

```
$('div img').load(function() {

$('div img').show();


});
```

Or this:

```
$('div').find('img').load(function() {

$('div img').show();

});
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work because once the browser loads even just a single image, it fires the event. Any ideas on how to load everything first ? Thanks!

Comment: If you set the dimensions like this: <img width="100" height="100" src="1.jpg" /> problem solved. In php you can grab the dimensions with http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep track of how many images have loaded:

```
var $images = $('div img'),
    preloaded = 0,
    total = $images.length;
$images.load(function() {
    if (++preloaded === total) {
        // Done!
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this will fail if IE8 caches the images.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. I'm going to leave it here in case anyone else makes that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not easy way to do this in a cross browser compatible way. But luckily there are 2 plugins out there that can make it painless.

Check out [waitforimages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) and [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

Then you can do:

```
$('div').waitForImages(function(){
  $(this).find('img').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://chipsandtv.com/articles/jquery-image-preload

Answer (score 0):

First, The modern browser can execute concurrently 6 request => Don't load so many image at the load time. If you have many images, you can set the images at the back 'src=""' or non set "src" attributes, And set after the first images loaded

Second, You can check "image was loaded" by using

```
 document.getElementById('#imageId').complete == !0
```

You can check with image with the largest size or the last image in DOM to make sure the others images were loaded.

Hope it 'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div with images').hide();
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $('#div with images').show();
});
```

Comment: Correct, but not for a div, its for all images in page.